# FloatingActionButton: Setting a custom background is not supported

Tags: android, kotlin, floating-action-button

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/insert_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/add"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/list_view"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/list_view"
        android:background="#649696"
        />
```

this code is ok, but add after two line is crask

```
        android:backgroundTint="#649696"
        app:rippleColor="#FFFFFF"
```

crash log:

Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/FloatingActionButton: Setting a custom background is not supported.

grade depences:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId ""
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

who can tell me how can i solved this problem

Comment: Use `app:backgroundTint` with namespace `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` instead of `android:background`(remove this attribute)

Comment: @VishalChhodwani ~ I'm specifically talking about **app:backgroundTint**; not *android:backgroundTint*. 
( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: I also talking about `app:backgroundTint` not `android:backgroundTint`.

Comment: Damn, did you even read his `build.gradle` ? He's targeting 23+ devices and also we use `app` attributes to provide back-compatibility. Stop wasting your time.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this warning will be also shown if you don't even set the background or tint. However, to get rid of it, you can set the attribute `android:background="@null"`, this will ignore it as suggested by a user from the [official materials github repository](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/283). (The reason for this issue is an internal issue, where some of those setters are called, which will probably fixed in a future release of the material design lib)

Comment: Don't set background using android:background. No need to do android:background="@null".
 If you want to change background color use app:backgroundTint or android:backgroundTint for api 21 and later

Answer (score 0):

Use below attribute for Background

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    ...
    app:backgroundTint="@color/ic_action"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_plus" />
```

Remove android:backgroundTint

Answer (score 0):

This is a stupid error, when use outside system api need use app as namespace instead of android

so the correct code is:

```
app:backgroundTint="#649696"
```

Comment: actually - the warning message appears even when using the "app" prefix

Answer (score 0):

> You need to add `app:backgroundTint="@color/your_color"` in your fab button to change the background color
>   button

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            app:elevation="2dp"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"  
            android:src="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:fabSize="normal" />
```